# How to remove a variable out of a list of variables in prolog?

Tags: prolog, dpll

I wanna implement the DPLL algorithm. Therefore i have to remove all occurrencies of a variable in a list of other variables, e.g. deleting `neg(X)` out of `[neg(X), pos(X), neg(Y), pos(Y)]` should return `[pos(X), neg(Y), pos(Y)]`.
I've tried some built-in predicates like exclude/3 or delete/3 but all left me with asuming `X = Y` and a result `[pos(X), pos(Y)]`, with all neg(_) removed, but I only want neg(X) removed and not neg(Y). Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Why don't you call your variables with lowercase letter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Logtalk library `list` object:

```
delete([], _, []).
delete([Head| Tail], Element, Remaining) :-
    (   Head == Element ->
        delete(Tail, Element, Remaining)
    ;   Remaining = [Head| Tail2],
        delete(Tail, Element, Tail2)
    ).
```

Sample call:

```
?- delete([neg(X), pos(X), neg(Y), pos(Y)], neg(X), Rest).
Rest = [pos(X), neg(Y), pos(Y)].
```

The key is to use the standard `==/2` term **equality** predicate instead of the standard `=/2` **unification** predicate.